# Filtering SmartTable that consists of multiple entity sets

Tags: sapui5

I have a [`sap/ui/comp/smarttable/SmartTable`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable) which receives data of one EntitySet (`MAINSet`). The table has 5 columns. I added three extra columns manually where I put data from another EntitySet (`DetailSet`) when a specific button is pressed. I do that manually by iterating throw the table and setting the properties like this:

```js
table.getModel().setProperty(sPath + "/EXAMPLE", EXAMPLE);
```

Filtering works fine for all the properties of the `MAINSet`. But filtering properties which I retrieve from the `DETAILSet` does not work with the following logic:

```js
var oBinding = this.getView().byId("table0").getBinding("items");
var aFilter = [];
var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
if (sQuery) {
  aFilter.push(new Filter("EXAMPLE", FilterOperator.Contains , sQuery));
}
oBinding.filter(aFilter);
```

Is there any way I can filter the SmartTable for the data received from the `DETAILSet`?

Comment: you can either add the `DETAILSet` columns while rendering the table and make it hidden and show columns after button press. Or, when you set property to table model, just do `model.refresh()`, that might update the items binding and can solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately `model.refresh` did not solve the problem. The `DETAILSET` should only be triggered when a specific button is pressed because of performance reasons. I get the data from `DETAILSET`, but the problem I have is with filtering the values provided by the `DETAILSET`. The table can only be filtered by Columns of the `MAINSET`. The SmartTable is referencing only to the `MAINSET` since SmartTables can only bind one EntitySet.